# C# MVC Build warning for Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.12.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a C# MVC project, it was working last week but when I started working again this week I am getting this warning and all the adjustment or changes I am making in the controllers doesn't reflect:

> Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxx, processorArchitecture=x86". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.

Hope someone can help me.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I'm seeing this on my references, so what I did is I deleted it then added it again now there's a different warning, please see below.

[image]

New Warning:

> The primary reference "Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.12.0, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2".

Comment: Have you looked at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36749143/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-aspnet-scaffolding-12-0)

Comment: Yeah saw that post before but I'm still developing in VS 2017, the answers there talks about deployment.

Comment: I solved it before deleting `obj` and `bin` folder. And then Cleaning and Rebuilding the solution.

Comment: Still no good, edited my question. Please see. Thanks